# In JQuery $(result) returns <not available> with some content

Tags: jquery

I have this JQuery piece of code:

```
if ($(result).first().hasClass('unauth')) {
    unauthorizeddialog(result);
} else {
    if (_ops.successAction == 'FillTarget') {
       $('.' + _ops.target).html(result);
    } else {
       alert('Alienform had an unexpected submit handling.');
    }
}
```

'result' comes from an ajax GET, the problem occurred when I receive something like:

```
<p class="ui-widget-content ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">
    No results to show
</p>
```

When I watch `$(result)` in the chrome js debugger it results in `<not available>` and the line `$(result).first().hasClass('unauth')` throws error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
<p class="ui-widget-content ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">
    No results to show
</p>
```

However, In contrast, everything works as expected when `result` contains something like:

```
<div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-state-error unauth">
    <h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">Unauthorized <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert fright"></span></h2>
    <p>
       You are not authorized to view this page!
    </p>
    <p>
       <label>U.R.L.:</label> /serviceorderdetail/getsales/<br />
       <label>User:</label> admin<br />
       <label>Date:</label> 2/15/2014 9:07:15 AM<br />
    </p>
    <p>
       This attempt has been logged and will be reviewed by a system administrator.
    </p>
    <p>
       <strong>Error: </strong>  - - 
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm baffled by this and I sense it might be something very basic since I've done this type of procedure several times before.

Any ideas on the why of this behaviour?

**UPDATE:**
For some reason MVC was returning spaces at the beginning of the HTML string and thanks to Dennis's reply I fixed it using `.trim()`.

Comment: What is `<not available>`?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that, when I watch $(result) in the chrome  debugger it results in <not available>.

Comment: @c0y0teX Do you get that `not available` when you check the response from server side for `$(result)`? And is this a some exceptional statement you wrote from server side? I never seen something like this.

Comment: Can you `console.log` just the result?  It looks like jQuery is throwing a syntax error when you try to parse the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glancing at the jQuery source, `Syntax error, unrecognized expression:` only happens when the Sizzle engine is being invoked, which should not happen for HTML strings.  Check that there are no spaces at the beginning of the the string, otherwise jQuery won't recognize it as HTML.

Comment: This was exactly the case, I fixed it using `.trim()`, thanks a bunch Dennis.